# Tailwind css is not being applied - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

I am working on a react application created using Vite. I am trying to use tailwind and followed the steps mentioned in the official docs of tailwind.
But my css is not being applied.
I am using react with typescript (tsx). Can someone please have a look at my code snippets and suggest me something that I may have missed in my configuration?

Here's a list of packages that I am using.

```
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.6"
"postcss": "^8.4.32",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"typescript": "^5.3.2",
"vite": "^5.0.0"
```

here is my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    export default {
      content: [
         "./index.html",
         "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
  }
```

and my postcss.config.js

```
export const plugins = {
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
};
```

I have included tailwind in my index.css as follows:

```
  /* ./src/index.css */
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
```

But I am unable to get any css applied when I run my app. i.e. in the following h1 tag.

```
<h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world...!
</h1>
```

I would appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: Are you importing "index.css" somewhere?

Comment: yes. in my index.css file. index.css is being imported in main.tsx file.


import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

Comment: Maybe stop the dev server, remove node_modules, start again... :man_shrugging_shoulders:

Comment: Already did that. No luck so far. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
postcss.config.js

export default {
plugins: {
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
}
}
```

Comment: Great. This solved my issue. Appreciate your help mate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).